# Bookmark specific word line and one line before each bookmark

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list like following:

```
  <th class="News">20</th>
  <td class="News"><a href="vector">Vector</a></td>
  <td class="News" style="text-align: right" title="Yesterday: 182">181<img src="/web/20040929104305im_/http://distrowatch.com/images/other/adown.png" alt=">" title="Yesterday: 182"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th class="News">21</th>
  <td class="News"><a href="turbolinux">Turbolinux</a></td>
  <td class="News" style="text-align: right" title="Yesterday: 176">177<img src="/web/20040929104305im_/http://distrowatch.com/images/other/aup.png" alt="<" title="Yesterday: 176"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th class="News">22</th>
  <td class="News"><a href="gnoppix">Gnoppix</a></td>
  <td class="News" style="text-align: right" title="Yesterday: 171">171<img src="/web/20040929104305im_/http://distrowatch.com/images/other/alevel.png" alt="=" title="Yesterday: 171"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th class="News">23</th>
  <td class="News"><a href="aurox">Aurox</a></td>
  <td class="News" style="text-align: right" title="Yesterday: 172">171<img src="/web/20040929104305im_/http://distrowatch.com/images/other/adown.png" alt=">" title="Yesterday: 172"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th class="News">24</th>
  <td class="News"><a href="buffalo">Buffalo</a></td>
  <td class="News" style="text-align: right" title="Yesterday: 163">162<img src="/web/20040929104305im_/http://distrowatch.com/images/other/adown.png" alt=">" title="Yesterday: 163"></td>
</tr>
```

Now I want to bookmark `.png" alt` lines and **one line before of each bookmarked lines** in notepad++ by regex.

I tried following Regular expressions but not worked:

```
^.+\.png" alt.*\R\K.+
^.+\.png" alt.*$\R(.+)$
^.+\.png" alt.*$\R\K^.+$
^.+\.png" alt.*$\R
^.+\.png" alt.*$\R^.+$
```

Where is my problem?

Comment: @Thefourthbird I want to bookmark one line before .png" alt not after!

Comment: Then capture the line before it? `(.*)\R.+\.png" alt\b` https://regex101.com/r/5BDoiS/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all your patterns you are matching the line after it.

If you want the line before it, it should be the other way around. You could capture the line if that is necessary and you only have to match the next line to the `alt` part.

```
(.*)\R.+\.png" alt\b
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5BDoiS/1).

Comment: can you tell me how can I bookmark all things except your regex? I mean (.*)\R.+\.png" alt\b

Comment: @PubgMobile Like this? `(.*)\R.+\.png" alt\b.*(*SKIP)(*F)|.+` See https://regex101.com/r/saLkOZ/1

Comment: ye please send as answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77461257/how-to-inverse-regex-areas-in-notepad