# How to inverse regex areas in notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have following list:

```
  <th class="News">14</th>
  <td class="News"><a href="pclinuxos">PCLinuxOS</a></td>
  <td class="News" style="text-align: right" title="Yesterday: 341">341<img src="/web/20050131094820im_/http://distrowatch.com/images/other/alevel.png" alt="=" title="Yesterday: 341"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th class="News">15</th>
  <td class="News"><a href="redhat">Red Hat</a></td>
  <td class="News" style="text-align: right" title="Yesterday: 290">289<img src="/web/20050131094820im_/http://distrowatch.com/images/other/adown.png" alt=">" title="Yesterday: 290"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th class="News">16</th>
  <td class="News"><a href="slax">SLAX</a></td>
  <td class="News" style="text-align: right" title="Yesterday: 274">275<img src="/web/20050131094820im_/http://distrowatch.com/images/other/aup.png" alt="<" title="Yesterday: 274"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th class="News">17</th>
  <td class="News"><a href="vine">Vine</a></td>
  <td class="News" style="text-align: right" title="Yesterday: 269">261<img src="/web/20050131094820im_/http://distrowatch.com/images/other/adown.png" alt=">" title="Yesterday: 269"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

I can select my target lines by following regex:

```
(.*)\R.+\.png" alt\b
```

[image]

Now I want to inverse my target lines using regex.
I used `^(?!.*(.*)\R.+\.png" alt\b).+\R` regex to inverse it but I failed and get following result!

[image]

**Why my regex only inverse one of lines? where is problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Notepad++ you can make use of [(*SKIP) and (*FAIL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex), and then match 1 or more times any char to not match empty lines.

To prevent partial matching, you can anchor the pattern, and you can omit the leading capture group if you want a match only:

```
^.*\R.+\.png" alt\b(*SKIP)(*F)|^.+
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dDM3JD/1)